# uploading image and text with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, image-uploading

i'm trying to create form which with which i can upload text and image both. But when i enter the information the texts only get saved but the image doesn't seem to appear the folder.

Part of my controller file

```
               $form_data = array(
                        'address' => set_value('address'),
                        'area' => set_value('area'),
                        'lat' => set_value('lat'),
                        'lng' => set_value('lng'),
                        'subject' => set_value('subject'),
                        'problem' => set_value('problem'),
                        'image' => '',//what to put here???
                        'time' => $now,

                        'register_id' =>set_value ('register_id'),
                        'category_id' => set_value('category_id'),
                        'city_city_id' => set_value('city_city_id'),
                        'status_status_id' => set_value('status_status_id')
                    );

      if ($this->report_model->SaveForm($form_data) == TRUE) 
   {
   redirect('report/success');

            }





               function do_upload()  
            {
          $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';

    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width']  = '1024';
    $config['max_height']  = '768';
    $this->upload->initialize($config); 
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);



}
```

View file

```
        $attributes = array('class' => '', 'id' => '');
                 echo form_open('report', $attributes); ?>

              <p>
    <label for="problem">problem detail:</label>
    <?php echo form_error('problem'); ?>
    <br /><input id="problem" type="text" name="problem"  value="<?php echo

                set_value('problem'); ?>"  />
                   </p>

          <p>Upload a image:


            <?php echo form_open_multipart('report/do_upload');?>

               <input type="file" name="image" size="20" />
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the file uploaded is called `userfile`

```
<input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
```

Change that `image` to `userfile` for your upload input element.

Otherwise define `image` as the name/id to use by the upload class.

> If you would like to set your own field name simply pass its value to
>   the do_upload function:

```
$field_name = "some_field_name";
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)
```

**Ref:** http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

---

**ACTUALLY...** seems you are all over the place (multiple forms?)

Just go to the reference link I provided, and start a single form, follow the user guide for best details, I think you are just confusing how to create a form under CI.

Comment: separately both form works just fine. but when i want to combine the both (like both image and the text) the texts appears but the image doesn't. Still trying to find the problem.Thanks for your help.:)

Comment: Did you not read my answer? You are not capturing proper file input name on your upload

Comment: If it works, please mark this as 'answer' (green checkmark) that is the proper method at SO.  Thanks.